# Segmentation fault (core dumped) / File Manager Search Bar

Tags: nautilus, crash, filemanager, search, segmentation-fault

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64 bits

Gnome Version: 3.36.8

Kernel Version: 5.11.0-40-generic

When I type something on file manager, the window simply crash.
I opened the file manager via command line with `nautilus --browser ~/Downloads/` and typed something on search bar again and the error displayed is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I searched the error on everywhere and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing a repository and enabling Canonical Partners repository. Probably was a conflict between them.

If you have the same problem try this steps:

- Open **Software & Updates**;
- Open **Other software** tab;
- Enable *Canonical Partners* repository;
- Disable/Remove all repositories (except Canonical Partners);
- Reboot system;

Try to open file manager and type something to confirm if the problem is solved, and in that case activate one of the repositories you had enabled and keep trying one by one to figure out what repository is broken/conflicting.